# How to prevent page from flashing to its original lightmode style between page transitions when darkmode is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, dom

My below code works 99% of the way. When the theme-switch is toggled the website changes all the associated elements to my darkmode styles. The darkmode is able to maintain its styles when changing to different pages using cookies.

The problem I'm experiencing is when changing to a different page the lightmode style for the page flashes for a split second before the darkmode style takes effect again automatically. I believe it's a page loading problem but I'm having trouble fixing it using the code I've already got setup.

I'm trying to make it so that the darkmode remains active from page to page. A clean transition without the flash of white or the orginal page style which is lightmode between pages.

```
<!-- DARK MODE TOGGLE SWITCH -->

                <div class="theme-switch" id="index-theme-switch">
                  <div class="switch"></div>
                </div>

<!-- /DARK MODE TOGGLE SWITCH -->
```

The below script is placed within my header.php file so that it affects all the pages accordingly. When the theme-switch is toggled all the below darkmode styles is applied to the pages:

```
<script>


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme-switch").click(function() {
    $(".theme-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $("body, div#margin-min, ul.menu, .sidenav").toggleClass("dark-theme");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme-switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".theme-switch").addClass("active");
    $("body, div#margin-min, ul.menu, .sidenav").addClass("dark-theme");
  }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme-switch").click(function() {
    $(".theme-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $("div#margin-min").toggleClass("dark-theme-marginmin");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme-switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".theme-switch").addClass("active");
    $("div#margin-min").addClass("dark-theme-marginmin");
  }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme-switch").click(function() {
    $(".theme-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $("p.uppercase, .page-id-536 li p, .page-id-91 p").toggleClass("dark-theme-description");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme-switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".theme-switch").addClass("active");
    $("p.uppercase, .page-id-536 li p, .page-id-91 p").addClass("dark-theme-description");
  }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme-switch").click(function() {
    $(".theme-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $("i.sf-icon-star-full, .page-id-536 i.sf-icon-star-full").toggleClass("dark-theme-star");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme-switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".theme-switch").addClass("active");
    $("i.sf-icon-star-full, .page-id-536 i.sf-icon-star-full").addClass("dark-theme-star");
  }
});


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme-switch").click(function() {
    $(".theme-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $("div.cell").toggleClass("dark-theme-cellborder");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme-switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".theme-switch").addClass("active");
    $("div.cell").addClass("dark-theme-cellborder");
  }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme-switch").click(function() {
    $(".theme-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $("li.menu-item").toggleClass("dark-theme-sitenavborder");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme-switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".theme-switch").addClass("active");
    $("li.menu-item").addClass("dark-theme-sitenavborder");
  }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme-switch").click(function() {
    $(".theme-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $(".left a, ul.menu").toggleClass("dark-theme-navlinks");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme-switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".theme-switch").addClass("active");
    $(".left a, ul.menu").addClass("dark-theme-navlinks");
  }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme-switch").click(function() {
    $(".theme-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $("span.btn-bg, span.inner").toggleClass("dark-theme-buttons");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme-switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".theme-switch").addClass("active");
    $("span.btn-bg, span.inner").addClass("dark-theme-buttons");
  }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme-switch").click(function() {
    $(".theme-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $(".navbar").toggleClass("dark-theme-mobile-navbar");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme-switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".theme-switch").addClass("active");
    $(".navbar").addClass("dark-theme-mobile-navbar");
  }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme-switch").click(function() {
    $(".theme-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $(".site-searchform input").toggleClass("dark-theme-search-input");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme-switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".theme-switch").addClass("active");
    $(".site-searchform input").addClass("dark-theme-search-input");
  }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme-switch").click(function() {
    $(".theme-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $(".color-cat0 a, .color-cat01 a, .color-cat2 a, .color-cat3 a, .color-cat4 a, .color-cat5 a, .color-cat6 a, .color-cat7 a, .color-cat8 a, .color-cat9 , .color-cat10 a, .color-cat11 a, .color-cat12 a, .color-cat13 a, .color-cat14 a, .color-cat15 a, .color-cat16 a").toggleClass("dark-theme-nav-pointer");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme-switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".theme-switch").addClass("active");
    $(".color-cat0 a, .color-cat01 a, .color-cat2 a, .color-cat3 a, .color-cat4 a, .color-cat5 a, .color-cat6 a, .color-cat7 a, .color-cat8 a, .color-cat9 , .color-cat10 a, .color-cat11 a, .color-cat12 a, .color-cat13 a, .color-cat14 a, .color-cat15 a, .color-cat16 a").addClass("dark-theme-nav-pointer");
  }
});



</script>
```

The CSS for Darkmode:

```
 .theme-switch .switch {
   background: white;
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   background: var(--background);
   border-radius: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 3px;
   left: 3px;
   transition: 0.5s all ease;
}

 .dark-theme {
   --background: #fff;
   --text: #000;
   background-color: var(--darkbackground) !important;
}

.dark-theme-marginmin {
   --background: #fff;
   --text: #000;
   border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
   background-color: var(--darkbackground) !important;
}

 .dark-theme-description {
 color: #d1d1d1 !important;
}

 .dark-theme-cellborder {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
 }

 .dark-theme-sitenavborder {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) !important;
 }

 .dark-theme-navlinks {

 }

 .dark-theme-buttons {
   --background: #fff;
   --text: #000;
   background-color: var(--darkbackground) !important;
   color: grey !important;
   border-color: grey !important;
}

 .dark-theme .theme-switch {
   background: var(--text);
}

 .dark-theme .theme-switch .switch {
   transform: translateX(14px);
}

 .dark-theme-star {
color: grey !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.dark-theme-mobile-navbar {
   --background: #fff;
   --text: #000;
   background-color: var(--darkbackground) !important;
}
}

.dark-theme-search-input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: #d1d1d1 !important;
}

.dark-theme-nav-pointer:hover:after {           /* Nav Hover Pointer*/
      border-right-color: var(--darkbackground) !important;
}

.dark-theme-nav-pointer:after {           /* Nav Hover Pointer*/
      border-right-color: var(--darkbackground) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I believe it's a page loading problem

You are partly correct. Yes it has to do with the page loading, and the JavaScript not running before the initial page paint. However you can't reliably solve this with front-end code. Since the initial paint of the screen might happen before your javascript has had a chance to execute due to implementation details of the specific browser.

My recommendation would be to inject the needed styles for each theme on your server and send your theme styles as inline css. Preferably with a background property set on the actual body, to allow the browser to paint the background on the initial layout with an appropriate color.
This way, when the user flips the toggle switch you send an HTTP request to the server, telling it about the updated theme preference. You may then use JavaScript to instantly apply the theme (the same way you are doing now) but the server will (if you've implemented it) make sure the right theme is applied by default the next time the page is loaded.

***Note:** If you are relying on browser cache to speed up the page load then you might need to fingerprint your html file to make sure that it updates when the theme changes.*

### Applying theme in JavaScript

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
document.querySelectorAll('h1').forEach(el => {
  el.style.color = 'white';
});
```

```html
<document>
  <body>
    <h1>Dark theme applied with js</h1>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--Above import are for simluated load times of vendor libraries-->
  <script src="#">/*pretend inport for our script*/</script>
</document>
```

### Applying theme inline as server rendered styles

```html
<document>
  <head>
    <style>
    body {
      background: black;
    }
    h1 {
      color: white;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dark theme applied with inline styles</h1>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--Above import are for simluated load times of vendor libraries-->
  <script src="#">/*pretend inport for our script*/</script>
</document>
```